# Is this string addition a valid expression?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, string-literals, user-defined-literals

I was curious if the compound assignment operators are valid for multiple parameters. My guess is += will have no side-effect but may not be the same case with "-=".

```
std::string a; 
a += "Hello" + " "+"World"; // doesn't compile
std::string name = "Old";
a += "Hello" + name +"World"; // compiles
```

Comment: Why didn't you just try to compile it to determine if it is valid?

Comment: @JesperJuhl To be fair, it's not because code compiles that it is valid.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Of course not (as I know you know I know). But it would have let OP add the additional info: "it compiles" or "it doesn't compile with this error: ..." . And doing some basic testing yourself (like "does this even compile?") is a good habit to get into.

Comment: They (not me) probably thought you did not do enough research before asking the question. That is a bit subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a valid expression because there is no operator + for string literals

```
"Hello" + " "+"World
```

(more precisely for pointers because in expressions string literals with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first symbols.)

Instead you could write

```
std::string a; 
( ( a += "Hello" ) += " " ) += "World";
```

But it would be more readable if to write

```
a += "Hello";
a += " ";
a += "World";
```

Or as **@Bathsheba** pointed out in a (valuable) comment to my answer you could use a user-defined string literal the following way

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    std::string a; 
    a += "Hello"s + " " + "World";

    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

As for this statement

```
a += "Hello" + name +"World";
```

then it can be rewriten using the operators defined for the class `std::basic_string`

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>
operator+(const charT* lhs, const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& rhs);
```

and

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>
operator+(basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>&& lhs, const charT* rhs);
```

like

```
a += operator +( operator +( "Hello", name ), "World" );
```

For example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::string name = "Old";

    a += operator +( operator +( "Hello ", name ), " World" ); 

    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Take into account that each operator returns an object of the type `std::basic_string` for which the `operator +` is defined. That is in each call of the operators there is present an object of the type `std::basic_string` as an argument.

Comment: Welcome back Vlad!

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks. I'm glad to meet you.:)

Comment: Or you could just write `a += "Hello"   " " "World"` or even ``a += "Hello World"`, if you are feeling adventurous.

Comment: @DanM. You are right but the question is about the operator +.

Comment: @bruno: It has hidden depths. Note that if `a += b` really was replaced with `a = a + b`, then the code would compile.

Comment: @DanM.: How about `a += "Hello"s + "" + "World"`?

Comment: @bruno or just no code at all since you never use `a` :P

Answer (score 4):

The compound assignment operator `+=` doesn't come into it.

You can use `+=` with `std::string` because [it defines the relevant overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D), but it only gets *one* argument.

And you've tried to pass, as that argument, an expression constructed by `+`ing multiple string literals. This will not compile.

Some alternatives, in this toy case, which may inspire a solution for whatever is your real case:

#### Option 1

```
// Multiple calls to +=
std::string a;
a += "Hello";
a += " ";
a += "World";
```

#### Option 2

```
// String literal concatenation!
std::string a; 
a += "Hello" " " "World";
```

#### Option 3

```
// Repeated std::string concat
std::string a;
a += std::string("Hello") + " " + "World";
```

#### Option 4

```
// Same
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::string a; 
a += "Hello"s + " " + "World";
```

#### Option 5

```
// Don't bother
std::string a;
a += "Hello World";
```

Comment: Why does the second example compiles ?

Comment: @ash007 [It's a language feature](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/254984/17853), albeit a little-known one.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `a += "Hello" + " " + "World"` is *grouped* as `a += ("Hello" + " " + "World")`.

The right hand side is a set of 3 `const char[]` literals. These decay to `const char*` pointers when applied to binary addition. Since you can't add pointers, the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic.

(Note that the ostensibly equivalent expression `a = a + "Hello" + " " + "World"` is compilable.)